# Adjusting graphical LaTeX text size in Matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, latex

I am trying this example:

http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/latex.html

Let's say I wanted to resize those labels. How? I can't figure out any LaTeX code, and 'fontsize' does not do the trick.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is the line that worked:

```
ylabel('$x_e, x_c$', 'interpreter','latex', 'fontsize', 32);
```

Obviously, between the dollar signs can be whatever appropriate LaTeX expression desired.

Answer (score 3):

This hits a sore spot when it comes to Matlab's support for (or use of) Latex.  The normal font-size commands from Latex aren't available.  (In Latex normally you'd just say `\Large{Text ... $x$}` or even `\normalsize ...`.)

To do this in a Matlab plot you can add fontsize spec at the end

```
title(['For $x$ and ...'], 'Interpreter', 'latex', 'fontsize', 14)
```

For more discussion and how to change font type as well see [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/247396/font-size-and-font-type).  Note that there are not so many fonts readily available in Matlab. To preserve sanity I'd keep this kind of tweaking to the minimum.

There is another method that will work anywhere in Matlab where you can use Latex -- in any text, in the middle of a string, etc: You can drop to Latex's lower level font specification.

```
title(['\fontsize{15}{0}\selectfont For $x$ and ...'], 'Interpreter', 'latex')
```

The first command `\fontsize{}{}` specifies the font, the second one `\selectfont` actually changes it for the rest of the text.  When you want to switch to a different font, even mid-string, you again issue `\fontsize{12}{0}\selectfont` and you have that font size after that point.  The only thing you need to change is the size (I used `15` and `12` as examples), the rest is boilerplate (for this purpose).

See what these things mean and more discussion in [this post](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/79244-set-latters-in-a-string-to-different-fontsizes-with-interpreter-latex). For far more detail on fonts in Matlab see [this article](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/matlab-latex-interface).  For how to change fonts across the whole document see [this post](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/114116).

There are yet other ways but it gets progressively trickier and this should be enough.  Probably the best advice is to set it once for the whole document.  That also makes sense typesetting-wise.

---

*Note.*     The font command of the second example must be given *outside of math mode*.  Latex has two major modes, text and math.  To make it go to 'math mode', where it processes everything as it were math symbols, you put a `$`, or `$$`.  (There are yet many other ways, but in Matlab's strings this is all you'll ever use.) When you want it to go back to typesetting text normally, you end math mode with another `$`, or `$$`. All math is in between `$...$`, everything else is normal text.

```
This is some text, now typeset some math: $y = x^2$ ... back to text.
```

*The font commands do not work in math mode but need be given outside the `$...$`*.  They will apply to any following math as well. In a plot command we'd say

```
ylabel(['\fontsize{16}{0}\selectfont $\dot{x}$'], 'interpreter','latex');
```

Comment: That did not work. Even doing something as exaggerated as this:

    ylabel(['$\fontsize{60}{0}\selectfont \dot{x}$'], 'interpreter','latex');

does not change the font. :(

Comment: @Phys251  (1) I'd recommend using the first form for plots. It's just simpler. (2) You don't put font spec inside 'math mode' -- it has to be outside of `$...$`.

Comment: @Phys251  Added a statement (to use font commands outside of math mode)  to the answer.  Let me know.

Comment: @Phys251  So in your example from the comment you'd say `ylabel(['\fontsize{60}{0}\selectfont $\dot{x}$'], 'interpreter','latex');`

Comment: ^ That is exactly what I did, yet the label did not resize.

Comment: @Phys251  In your comment here  the font-command in _inside the dollars_.  You have `ylabel(['$\fontsize...$'])`.  You need `ylabel(['\fontsize... $...$'])`.  It would be very strange that it doesn't work.  I use this all the time, and I tried it when I posted the answer.  I tried it right in the Matlab shell, without  any particular settings.  What Matlab are you using?  Do you have something very special set up?

Comment: @Phys251  If you copy-and-paste the lines from my answer, for `title` and `ylabel` -- do they work?

Comment: No. Literally copy-pasting exactly what you gave me does not work. Matlab refuses to resize the LaTeX text labels.

Comment: @Phys251  Oh.  Then you may have some global settings somewhere which prevent this to work. Can you change fonts at all? Try the way from a link in my answer for changing fonts for the whole document -- the commands are:  `fontsize = 12; set(0,'defaultaxesfontsize', fontsize);
set(0,'defaulttextfontsize', fontsize);` (somewhere in the beginning).  I'll think more about what it can be.  What I post is a well-known, standard way to set fonts.  You have something else going on.

Comment: @Phys251  Also -- never mind their example, set up some simple plot from scratch.  (Their example doesn't even work for me, I tried it.)

Comment: Got it. Here was the line that worked:

ylabel('$x_e, x_c$', 'interpreter','latex',  'fontsize', 32);

Comment: @Phys251  great :).  That is the first recommended way in my answer -- I think that it is the best way to go.